# Timeline View per Year (DeveExpress control)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, scheduler

I am trying to use timeline Control as the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIvB7.png).
I use this code but really I don't know where the problem, cause it's working.

```
public CollectionView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        schedulerControl1.Start = new DateTime(2009, 1, 1);
        schedulerControl1.TimelineView.Scales.Clear();
        schedulerControl1.TimelineView.Scales.Add(new TimeScaleYear());

        BindingList<ModelResource> resourceList = new BindingList<ModelResource> {
            new ModelResource() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "One" },
            new ModelResource() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Two" },
            new ModelResource() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Three" },
        };

        BindingList<ModelAppointment> appointmentList = new BindingList<ModelAppointment> {
            new ModelAppointment() { StartTime = new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), EndTime = new DateTime(2011, 07, 01), Subject = "PL: TT.MM.JJ SL: TT.MM.JJ", ResourceId = resourceList[0].Id },
            new ModelAppointment() { StartTime = new DateTime(2011, 06, 01), EndTime = new DateTime(2012, 11, 01), Subject = "PL: TT.MM.JJ SL: TT.MM.JJ", ResourceId = resourceList[1].Id },
            new ModelAppointment() { StartTime = new DateTime(2012, 10, 01), EndTime = new DateTime(2014, 02, 01), Subject = "PL: TT.MM.JJ SL: TT.MM.JJ", ResourceId = resourceList[2].Id },
        };

        //SchedulerControl.Storage.ResourceStorage.DataSource = resourceList;
        //SchedulerControl.Storage.AppointmentStorage.DataSource = appointmentList;
        schedulerControl1.DataStorage.Resources.DataSource = resourceList;
        schedulerControl1.DataStorage.Appointments.DataSource = appointmentList;
        //schedulerStorage1
    }
```

and the Model is :

```
public class ModelAppointment
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long Label { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
    public int EventType { get; set; }
    public object ResourceId { get; set; }

    public ModelAppointment()
    {
    }
}

public class ModelResource
{
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ModelResource()
    {
    }
}
```

It should be look like the screenshot but nothing shows in the schedulerControl, empty data.
As you see the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SAUS.png).

**EDIT :**
As Svetlana mention for the Mapping:
This the code :

```
public LifeCycleCollectionView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private BindingList<LifecycleResource> CustomResourceCollection = new BindingList<LifecycleResource>();
    private BindingList<LifecycleAppointment> CustomEventList = new BindingList<LifecycleAppointment>();


    private void LifeCycleCollectionView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitResources();
        InitAppointments();

        CreateTimeScales();
    }

    private void CreateTimeScales()
    {
        schedulerControl1.Views.TimelineView.Scales.Clear();
        schedulerControl1.Views.TimelineView.Scales.Add(new TimeScaleYear());
        //schedulerControl1.Views.TimelineView.Scales.Add(new TimeScaleMonth());
        //schedulerControl1.Views.TimelineView.Scales.Add(new TimeScaleDay());
        //schedulerControl1.Views.TimelineView.Scales.Add(new TimeScaleFixedInterval(TimeSpan.FromHours(3)));
    }

    private void InitResources()
    {
        ResourceMappingInfo mappings = this.schedulerStorage1.Resources.Mappings;
        mappings.Id = "ResID";
        mappings.Color = "ResColor";
        mappings.Caption = "Name";

        CustomResourceCollection.Add(CreateCustomResource(1, "Project Pre-Study", Color.PowderBlue));
        CustomResourceCollection.Add(CreateCustomResource(2, "Project Execution", Color.PaleVioletRed));
        CustomResourceCollection.Add(CreateCustomResource(3, "Project Closure", Color.PeachPuff));
        this.schedulerStorage1.Resources.DataSource = CustomResourceCollection;
    }

    private LifecycleResource CreateCustomResource(int res_id, string caption, Color ResColor)
    {
        LifecycleResource cr = new LifecycleResource();
        cr.ResID = res_id;
        cr.Name = caption;
        cr.ResColor = ResColor;
        return cr;
    }

    private void InitAppointments()
    {
        AppointmentMappingInfo mappings = this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings;
        mappings.Start = "CycleBegin";
        mappings.End = "CycleEnd";
        mappings.Subject = "Comment";
        mappings.ResourceId = "OwnerId";
        mappings.AppointmentId = "IDLifeCycle";
        mappings.Description = "GoLiveDate";

        GenerateEvents(CustomEventList);
        this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.DataSource = CustomEventList;
    }

    private void GenerateEvents(BindingList<LifecycleAppointment> eventList)
    {
        eventList.Add(CreateEvent(schedulerStorage1.Resources[1].Caption + " comment 1", schedulerStorage1.Resources[1].Id, 0, 10, false));
        //int count = schedulerStorage1.Resources.Count;

        //for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        //{
        //    Resource resource = schedulerStorage1.Resources[i];
        //    string subjPrefix = resource.Caption + "'s ";
        //    eventList.Add(CreateEvent(subjPrefix + "Phase 1", resource.Id, 2, 5, false));
        //    eventList.Add(CreateEvent(subjPrefix + "Phase 2", resource.Id, 3, 6, true));
        //    eventList.Add(CreateEvent(subjPrefix + "Phase 3", resource.Id, 0, 10, false));
        //}
    }

    private LifecycleAppointment CreateEvent(string subject, object resourceId, int status, int label, bool allDay)
    {
        LifecycleAppointment apt = new LifecycleAppointment();
        apt.Comment = subject;
        apt.OwnerId = resourceId;
        //Random rnd = RandomInstance;
        //int rangeInMinutes = 60 * 24;
        if (allDay)
        {
            apt.CycleBegin = DateTime.Today;
            //apt.AllDay = true;
        }
        else
        {
            apt.CycleBegin = new DateTime(2019, 01, 01);
            apt.CycleEnd = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01);
        }
        //apt.Status = status;
        //apt.Label = label;
        return apt;
    }
```

But I don't know where is the problem, see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsGBJ.png) result of code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set SchedulerControl.GroupType = SchedulerGroupType.Resource;

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have created all the necessary mappings for appointments and resources as described in the [Mappings](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15468/Controls-and-Libraries/Scheduler/Data-Binding/Mappings) help topic.